# Prevent python truncating data used as a key

Tags: python, dictionary, key, truncate

I have a dictionary of latitude and longitude coordinates, and I am trying to index that dictionary with other coordinates. However, my coordinate get truncated inside my tuple. For example:

Value of the tuple:

```
In [17]: latLon
Out[17]: (37.540567000000003, -77.436044999999993)
```

When indexing:

```
KeyError: u'no item named (37.540567, -77.436045)'
```

How can I prevent python from truncating these values, so I can still use it as a key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using floating point numbers either use strings, where you can control the format, or decimals from the `decimal` library.

You need to do this because floating point numbers are rarely precise e.g.:

```
>>> ot = 1.0/10
>>> ot
0.10000000000000001
>>> decimal.Decimal(1)/10
Decimal('0.1')
```